# Entity Framework имя столбца

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Как можно присвоить столбцу имя, в котором присутствует пробел.

```
MainDG.ItemsSource = (from table in context.Работник select new { table.ID, Должность = table.Должность.Название, table.ФИО, Дата_рождения = table.ДР }).ToList();
```

Например, как здесь можно присвоить столбцу имя "Дата рождения" а не Дата_рождения ?

Comment: что это за ужас?

Comment: Что именно?

Comment: идентификаторы, записанные не латиницей (это в общем-то дурной тон как минимум. А как максимум - источник неочевидных проблем). Ну и сам по себе ваш вопрос. Вы хотите сделать идентификатор с пробелом? Это противоречсит синтаксису как C# так и SQL (в который в итоге должны "маппиться" ваши классы)

Comment: Тут я заполняю DataGrid и в рез-те получается таблица с заголовками столбцов ID, Должность, ФИО, Датарождения. Как вывести Дата рождения в заголовке, а не Датарождения, т.е. задать псевдоним.

Comment: значит вы делаете что-то не так. Я так понимаю это WPF? Я не занимаюсь этой технологией, поэтому к сожалению не смогу дать точного рецепта, но могу со стопроцентной уверенностью сказать, что наименования полей в ваших анонимных (и не анонимных) типах никоим образом не должны совпадать с заголовками столбцов в ваших контролах. Это совершенно разные сущности

Answer (score 1):

Набросал вот такую штуку, возможно поможет:

```
// C#
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var source = new[]
    {
        new { Id = 1, Name = "John" },
        new { Id = 2, Name = "Joe" },
        new { Id = 3, Name = "Stanley" },
        new { Id = 4, Name = "Andrew" },
    };

    MyGrid.ItemsSource = source;
}

// XAML
<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
              Margin="45,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Идентификатор" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
       </DataGrid.Columns>    
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

Получаем вот что:

[image]

Впрочем, возможно, есть более правильный вариант - еще раз повторю, с WPF знаком слабо

Comment: Проблема в том что в один DataGrid необходимо загружать выбранную таблицу, а их несколько, т.е. через xaml я не могу задать заголовки, они меняются

Comment: тогда не очень понятен смысл всей этой затеи. Зачем в один грид требуется грузить несколько таблиц да еще и судя по всему различной размерности? Скорее всего это говорит о плохой спроектированности вашей системы. 

В любом случае возможность писать заголовки столбцов грида есть. Можно через xaml, можно с помощью c#. А определить, куда и что записывать в зависимости от загружаемой таблицы - дело техники.

Comment: @Stepan Kurennyh: в качестве workaround можете брать имя столбца из таблицы, заменять в нём подчёркивания на пробелы и выводить.

Comment: если автор хочет названия столбцов по "русски" то тут собственно вариантов наверно много нет, названия столбцов писать в коде, или может в ресурсах. тоже знаком слабо было бы интересно если есть другие варианты